# xslt - Remove comma from last element

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I have the following XSLT macro (in Umbraco)

```
<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$currentPage/imageList/multi-url-picker" />
</xsl:template>
      <xsl:template match="url-picker">
        <xsl:variable name="url"><xsl:value-of select="./url" /></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', $url, '&quot;,')" />
    </xsl:template>
```

I would like to not add the comma to the last url-picker in the collection.
How would I go about doing this?

**Edit:** The XML schema, just for reference:

```
<multi-url-picker>
<url-picker mode="URL">
    <new-window>True</new-window>
    <node-id />
    <url>http://our.umbraco.org</url>
    <link-title />
</url-picker>
<url-picker mode="Content">
    <new-window>False</new-window>
    <node-id>1047</node-id>
    <url>/homeorawaytest2.aspx</url>
    <link-title />
</url-picker>
<url-picker mode="Media">
    <new-window>False</new-window>
    <node-id>1082</node-id>
    <url>/media/179/bolero.mid</url>
    <link-title>Listen to this!</link-title>
</url-picker>
<url-picker mode="Upload">
    <new-window>False</new-window>
    <node-id />
    <url>/media/273/slide_temp.jpg</url>
    <link-title />
</url-picker>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a more efficient solution. Also I have included some good-practice recommendations for defining variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Use**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>    

    <xsl:template match="url">
        <xsl:if test="not(position()=1)">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', ., '&quot;')" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (none was provided!):

```
<url-picker>
  <url>1</url>
  <url>2</url>
  <url>3</url>
</url-picker>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
"1","2","3"
```

**Do note**:

1. You don't need the variable `$url`.
2. If you need such variable, never create a child node (this results in an RTF). always use the `select` attribute of `xsl:variable`:

**Instead of**:

```
<xsl:variable name="url"><xsl:value-of select="./url" /></xsl:variable>
```

**write**:

```
<xsl:variable name="url" select="url" />
```

.3. It is a good practice to use some naming convention for variables, so that if the `$` is skipped accidentally, the name will not easily be the same as a name of an existing element. For example use:

```
<xsl:variable name="vUrl" select="url" />
```

Comment: Also note in this solution, whereas many people insert a comma after every element except the last, Dimitre inserts it before every element except the first. On many processors this is likely to be more efficient because it doesn't require look-ahead processing.

Comment: @Dimitre - Thank you for the detailed answer, and the extra two cents :) Great info for the beginning xslt user.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it will work in your case, because I'm not sure of the current context where the `url-picker` template is called, but you could add an `xsl:if`...

```
<xsl:template match="url-picker">
  <xsl:variable name="url"><xsl:value-of select="./url" /></xsl:variable>
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', $url, '&quot;')" />
  <xsl:if test="not(position()=last())">
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: It seems that you are not testing for the right condition -- the test will always return `false`

Comment: It should be not(position()=last()). The value of last() is always greater than zero, so converting it to a boolean always gives true.

Comment: Ahh, thank you for catching that Dimitre and Dr Kay. Thanks for the edit Mads.

Answer (score 2):

You could also check the next following sibling:

```
  <xsl:template match="url-picker">
    <xsl:variable name="url"><xsl:value-of select="./url" /></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', $url, '&quot;')" />
     <xsl:if test="following-sibling::url-picker">
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```